# Passing POST values to an Element Value

Tags: php

As the title says how am i able to perform that this is what i got:

This is the container :

```
   <select name="entrylevel">
   <options> val </option>
```

And this is how i

```
<?php $lvl=$_POST['entrylevel']; ?>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"  name="level" value="$lvl">
```

Currently its just spatting out $lvl at my text element. Would appreciate any help what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it your markup is wrong. You should use `<option>` not `<options>`. Next, you shall add value attribute like this `<option value="val">any text</option>`, so it all should look like this:

```
<select name="entrylevel">
<option value="val"> val </option>
```

and the code

```
<?php $lvl=$_POST['entrylevel']; ?>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"  name="level" value="<?php echo $lvl; ?>">
```

or in a bit more clean and corrected fashion:

```
<?php
$lvl = $_POST['entrylevel'];
printf('<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="level" value="%s">',
       htmlspecialchars($lvl));
?>
```

BTW: `type="text"` is default value if not specified, so it could be skipped but keeping it is not a bug anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's needed tell to PHP to print the variable value.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"  name="level" value="<?=$lvl?>">
```

This is the short syntax equivalent to:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"  name="level" value="<?php echo $lvl; ?>">
```